# How to output table to LaTeX after svy: tabulate two way

Tags: latex, output, stata, survey

I am trying to output a table to TeX after using `svy: tab`. Consider this example:

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r16/nhanes2f, clear
svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt], strata(stratid)
eststo sexrace: svy, subpop(rural): tab sex race, row percent format(%9.3g)
esttab sexrace
```

But this gives me only the cell percentages, not the row percentages. I ran `ereturn list` and it seems that these row percentages are not stored at all; they are used only to display the results.

I have also tried:

```
tabout sex race using table2.tex, replace c(row) layout(row) svy stats(chi2) percent
```

but I get different numbers.

Note: if you have not already installed `estout` and `tabout`, to run the above commands you need to install the two packages thus:

```
ssc install estout
ssc install tabout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r16/nhanes2f, clear
svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt], strata(stratid)

svy, subpop(rural): tab sex race, row percent format(%9.3g)

--------------------------------------
1=male,   | 1=white, 2=black, 3=other 
2=female  | White  Black  Other  Total
----------+---------------------------
     Male |  94.3   3.87   1.79    100
   Female |  96.1   2.87   .993    100
          | 
    Total |  95.2   3.37    1.4    100
--------------------------------------
  Key:  row percentage

  Pearson:
    Uncorrected   chi2(2)         =   19.0178
    Design-based  F(1.81, 52.45)  =    2.1654     P = 0.1294


tabout sex race if rural == 1 using table2.tex, style(tex) ///
replace c(row) svy stats(chi2) f(3) mult(100)

        1=white, 2=black, 3=other
        White   Black   Other   Total
        %       %       %       %
1=male, 2=female
Male    94.346  3.865   1.789   100.000
Female  96.137  2.870   0.993   100.000
Total   95.231  3.373   1.396   100.000
Pearson: Uncorrected chi2(2)= 19.018
Design-based F(1.81, 52.45)= 2.165
P-value= 0.129
```

Comment: ok, thanks, the _mult(100)_ option gave me an error but it worked fine when I used _percent_ instead. I realize that I really had not grasped how `tabout` works. It is different from `esttab` that outputs previously stored results: rather, `tabout` creates the tabulations on its own and also outputs them to LaTex.

Comment: @tt1977 `percent` has no effect in the context of the example you provided only `mult` does. What version of Stata and `tabout` do you use and what operating system?

Comment: I use Stata SE 16. Without the `percent` option, I get decimals. If I add the option, I get percentages, which is what I want.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem on both Mac and Windows using the latest version of `tabout`. Without the `mult` option I only get proportions not percentages. The `percent` option does not make any difference.

Comment: Thanks, @Pearly. I have Mac Os High Sierra, version 10.13.6, Stata SE 16, and for `tabout`, I have Version 2.0.7 5 jan 2015 (sorry, forgot to include all the info before). I actually just updated to High Sierra today and I reran your code again, with the `mult(100)` option and I still get the same error: _option mult() not allowed_, and the error is _r(198)_. And, yes, without the `mult(100)` option I get proportions. If I use instead `percent`, I get percentages. In any event, this is not so much an issue for me, as I can get what I asked for in the original question.  Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, you are using an older version of `tabout`, which does not have the `multiplier` option. This is why you get the aforementioned error. The [latest version](http://tabout.net.au/docs/home.php) of `tabout` is 3.